# IE8 and earlier CSS background won't work even if I only have 1?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, background-image, background-color

I'm not sure why it won't load my background color nor image if I'm not using multiple backgrounds on 1 element. ("IE8 and earlier do not support multiple background images on one element.")

```
#header1 {
  background: #191919 url(Site-in-development.png) left no-repeat;
  padding-top:15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;}
```

Even when I remove the img and leave only the color it won't display. Any ideas?

http://www.nobodyfilm.org/overview-and-production.html 
(If you have IE9 press F12 and you can change it to IE8 and or 7.) Thanks!

Comment: I know it's not answering the question, but don't do that with an image. Do it with text and if needed, a font face

Comment: Yeah I'm aware that it's a bad practice. Having a img was a faster choice. I wanted a decent font and had no time to go search webfonts. I'll remove it anyway so it's fine, but good pointing that out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE8 [doesn't recognise](http://caniuse.com/#feat=html5semantic) the `<header>` element (or any of the other HTML5 elements). IE8 is simply not seeing the element, no matter how it is styled. You need to use something like [html5shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) to make IE8 pretend to be a modern browser.

Including the html5shiv JavaScript file in a page can be achieved like so:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Also see http://blog.whatwg.org/supporting-new-elements-in-ie for a bit more background (no pun intended) on what the shiv does.

Comment: thanks. I'll better read the link in a second, but having already downloaded and tried to install I see it has a bunch of files (including multiple html5shiv.js) instead of one .js. I'm quite new at this so mind telling me how can link to entire folder (from html) so it can pick the appropriate files at will? Or should I select the .js either from src or dist folder? I'll google this in a sec :P

Comment: Sure, you only need the `html5shiv.js` file, ideally surrounded by [**conditional comments**](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) so it is only downloaded by IE8 and below. Edited my answer to include an example.

Answer (score 0):

According to [**the documentation**](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/background), it should be

```
background: { 
   background-color 
   background-image 
   background-repeat
   background-attachment 
   background-position | inherit 
} ;
```

Try changing your code to:

```
background: #191919 url(Site-in-development.png) no-repeat scroll left;
```

In the linked documentation, under the **Compatibility** section, you can see the tons of buggy behaviors performed by IE from IE6 up to IE8 (and by Safari up to 2.0 too) related to the `background` property.

Comment: I'll read the link in a second, but about changing the code to what you suggested.. am I missing something cause it's the exact code in my original post :>?

Comment: you put left no-repeat. I put no-repeat left. The order of params matters :)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
#header1 {
background-image: url(Site-in-development.png);
background-color: #191919;
background-position:left;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
padding-top:15px;
border-bottom: 1px solid white;}
```